# How to install package manager in java based docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apt, netcat

I am developing an application using SpringBoot and Java with Docker.

I want to install [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) in my application so that I can check if a specific container is up before my spring application starts.

I have tried

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install netcat && apt-get clean
```

But it says apt-get is not found.

I am not sure how can I install any package manager in my java based application.

Or is there any other I can get net-cat installed.

Below is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install netcat && apt-get clean
ADD target/student.jar student.jar
EXPOSE 2018
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","student.jar"]
```

Comment: Does the error occur during `docker build` ? Also can you `docker run` the `openjdk:8` container, step into it and try to execute `apt-get` there?

Comment: error comes while building the image

Comment: **Also can you docker run the openjdk:8 container, step into it and try to execute apt-get there? ** I am not that advanced at docker yet. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: `docker build . -t yourtag` to build (you would need to remove the `RUN` line from `Dockerfile`), then `docker run -it yourtag /bin/bash` should put you into the running container's `bash`. Then you can try to execute `apt-get install`.

Comment: TBH not sure if `docker run -it` works on windows though and can't really find any docs on that.

Comment: try: microdnf install some-package [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67826235/8927135)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get` is package manager for Debian-based Linux distros (including Ubuntu and others).

Try `apk add` instead.

Also, if you are using package managers in your `Dockerfile`, it is considered a good practice to **explicitly specify Linux distro**. In your case you can use `openjdk:8-jdk-stretch` variant or any other, where distro is specified.

Answer (score 1):

I can get a successful `docker build` with this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install netcat && apt-get clean
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

and `apt-get` works just fine. As far as I can tell `openjdk:8` is Ubuntu (or at least Debian based). Even if I run

```
docker build . -t stackexample
docker run -it stackexample
```

and get inside the container, running `netcat` opens the netcat cmd.

Comment: Which OS are you using for Docker?

Comment: @MehrajMalik Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Probably it's because I am using Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Hmm. I would have thought that the `build` stage would happen in the 'same' VM just like a container would run in. Also I find it weird that it would only be unable to do `apt-get` but do everything else.

Comment: Now I come to know Why MACs are so expensive :P