# docker image: openjdk:15: how to install python inside it

Tags: java, docker

I want to create an image of openjdk15 and python

I am trying the Dockerfile for buid

```
FROM    openjdk:15
RUN yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7
RUN yum install -y python36
```

But when i try to build the image it shows

```
/bin/sh: yum: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I checked the image also

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint ""  openjdk:15 sh -c "cat /etc/os-release"
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.3"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.3"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.3"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:3:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
```

Comment: Why do these need to be the same image; can you build a second image `FROM python`?

Comment: i have to add openjdk into t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that yum is not available on this image. It uses `microdnf` as package manager. Simply use following dockerfile to install python 3.6 :

```
FROM    openjdk:15
RUN microdnf install python36
```

After building and running a container with shell process I received :

```
bash-4.4# python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
```